# getting navigator.getUserMedia() no longer works in insecure origins

Tags: javascript, html

I am using navigator.getUserMedia to capture webcam images in html5.It works fine till last week.Now getting messages like getUserMedia()  no longer works  in insecure origins and capturing image from webcam broken . I searched about getUserMedia in web and find it is deprecated and browsers do not support it future. Is there any alternative function for  getUserMedia that works in all browsers.

my html code is

```
  <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
  <button id="snap" class="sexyButton">Snap</button>
   <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

and script function is

```
         <script>
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
            video = document.getElementById("video"),
            videoObj = { "video": true },
            errBack = function(error) {
                console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code); 
            };
        if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
            navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
                video.src = stream;
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        } else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        }

        // Trigger photo take
        document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
        });
    }, false);

         </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome now (as of 47+) enforces a new security rule that pages using `getUserMedia` must be served over HTTPS. This is to reduce the risk of malicious actors using camera or microphone devices to spy on users. It has been announced for over 4 months.

- https://twitter.com/juberti/status/659192698214023168
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/efuWL9JqoOo

As for your other comment that "getUserMedia in web and find it is deprecated and browsers do not support it future" - this is entirely incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 47, getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins
Few days ago Chrome 47 has been released.

One major change is WebRTC won’t work without HTTPS.
According internal security policy Chrome browser does not support getUserMedia() for unsecure pages since version 47. So you will not be able to use microphone if your page is not HTTPS.

http://flashphoner.com/getusermedia-no-longer-works-on-insecure-origins/